# How to prevent a form submit if some of the input areas are not filled

Tags: javascript, html, css, forms

as the title says i need help with this part of the code

```
function myFunction() {
var x,t,y,z,u;
```

i need to use this part to check if everything is filled, and if it isnt the form must not be submitted

```
document.getElementById("gumb").onclick=function(event){
   var slanje_forme=true;
   if (slanje_forme!=true)event.preventDefault();

}
x = document.getElementById("NazivProizvoda").value;
t = document.getElementById("sifra").value;
y = document.getElementById("kategorija").value;
z = document.getElementById("opisProizvoda").value;
u = document.getElementById("cijena").value;

if (isNaN(x) || x.length < 5 || x.length > 30) {
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "Naziv mora imati 5 do 30znakova!";
    NazivProizvoda.style.border="1px red";
} 
else if(isNaN(t) || t.length != 10)
{ document.getElementById("demo1").innerHTML = "Sifra mora imati 10 znakova";
        sifra.style.border="1px red";
}
else if(isNaN(z) || z.length < 10 || z.length > 100)
{document.getElementById("demo2").innerHTML = "Opis mora biti izmedu 10 i 100 znakova!"; 
        opisProizvoda.style.border="1px red";
}
else if(isNaN(u))
{ document.getElementById("demo3").innerHTML = "Cijena mora biti napisana";
        cijena.style.border="1px red";
}
<!--if else(isNaN(y) || t.length != 10)-->
<!--{}-->

else {
    text = "Input OK";
}
 document.getElementById("demo4").innerHTML = text;


}
```

my problem is that i dont know how to wrap all of the if statements within the 
preventDefault() or 
return false, 
do i need to write it like this

```
else if(isNaN(u))
  { document.getElementById("demo3").innerHTML ="Cijena mora biti napisana";
        cijena.style.border="1px red";
}
```

Comment: just  `return false` whenever an error occurred. however this question might be a duplicate!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [event.preventDefault() vs. return false](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1357118/event-preventdefault-vs-return-false)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## HTML

1. Wrap your form controls in a `<form>` tag.
2. Add [`required` attribute](https://www.wufoo.com/html5/required-attribute/) to each form control that needs the user to complete.

*See **Demo 1***

---

## JavaScript

Programatically this can be done with **[`setAttribute()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/setAttribute)**. In **Demo 2**, we are using the [**HTMLFormControlsCollection API**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLFormControlsCollection) to reference all `<form>` tags and their form controls. Although some **[form controls](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Content_categories#Form-associated_content)** do not need the `required` attribute, it is harmless yet it is messy markup. [`removeAttribute()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/removeAttribute) method can be used to clean them up or a more precise method could be used like [**`querySelectorAll()`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll) in **Demo 3**.

*See **Demo 2** and **Demo 3***

---

### Testing

Click the <kbd>Submit</kbd> button with and then without text in `<input>` text tag. In each demo the `<form>` tag is setup to send to a **[live test server](https://httpbin.org)**. Upon a successful submission of data the test server will send a response. If an `<input>` tag is empty, the `submit` event is cancelled and a tooltip will remind the user to enter data in the applicable form control.

---

### Demo 1

```html
<form id='F' action="https://httpbin.org/post" method="post">
  <label>Name: </label>
  <input id="F0" name='F0' required placeholder="First" >
  <input id="F1" name='F1' required placeholder="Last">
  <input type="submit">
</form>
```

---

### Demo 2

```js
const F = document.forms.F;
const fx = F.elements;

for (let f = 0; f < fx.length; f++) {
  fx[f].setAttribute("required", true);
}
```

```html
<form id='F' action="https://httpbin.org/post" method="post">
  <label>Name: </label>
  <input id="F0" name='F0' placeholder="First">
  <input id="F1" name='F1' placeholder="Last">
  <input type="submit">
</form>
```

---

### Demo 3

```js
var inputs = document.querySelectorAll('input[type=text]');

inputs.forEach(function(fc, idx, inputs) {
  fc.setAttribute("required", true);
});
```

```html
<form id='F' action="https://httpbin.org/post" method="post">
  <label>Name: </label>
  <input id="F0" name='F0' type="text" placeholder="First">
  <input id="F1" name='F1' type="text" placeholder="Last">
  <input type="submit">
</form>
```